# Why is map function not working as expected? ReactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I've got a `.map` function inside of `return`.
Now every data I've managed to return expect one array of objects that I've have.

So how data looks (sorry for the screenshot, hard to copy and paste over here):

[image: picture of data]

So in code I would use `bankname` like this:

```
{a &&
   a.map((item) =>
     item.banka.bankname.map((its) => (
         <div className='container p-3 my-3 bg-dark text-white'>
            <h2>{its}</h2>
         </div>
      ))
)}
```

And everything works fine. Now problem hits when I want to use `eks,type` inside of this container(where `its` is located). Now I cannot in any way to get it displaying `bankname, eks, type` 3 times(foreach bankname, eks, type make individual container). I've been trying whole day with various solution: place `banka` into array, place keys of `banka` at object etc. etc. I'm always getting all three into one single container or I'm getting 9 times of it when I map each key of `banka`

So I'm hoping that my code look like:

```
{a &&
   a.map((item) =>
     item.banka.map((its) => (
         <div className='container p-3 my-3 bg-dark text-white'>
            <h2>{its.bankaname}</h2>
            <h3>{its.eks}</h3>
            <h3>{its.type}</h3>
         </div>
      ))
)}
```

But when I'm using this I get error: item.banka.map is not a function.

Also whole code u can find on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hwps4tjm/

Any ideas on how to manage this? Thanks

Comment: From the screenshot `item.banka` is an *object*, not an array.

Comment: `map` works on array, and you're trying to use it on an object type

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've needed to use object instead of array because of key:values pairs

Comment: OK, but that doesn't mean it will have a map method.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but would it still work? Because there is only 3 keys inside of an object, where values have an array of n items inside.

Comment: Clearly not, hence the error you're asking about.

Comment: To iterate I'd try something like [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) instead of `Array.map`, which is available only in Array not in Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{a &&
    a.map((item) =>
      item.banka.bankname.map((its, index) => (
     <div className='container p-3 my-3 bg-dark text-white'>
        <h2>{its}</h2>
        <h2>{item.banka.eks[index]}</h2>
        <h2>{item.banka.type[index]}</h2>
     </div>
  ))
)}
```